# How to add a hat to a greek letter in a graph label in excel 2013

Tags: excel, plot, symbols, equations

I need to add the following character in the Y-axis label of an Excel 2013 plot: the greek letter xi, with a hat ^ on top, and all that with a subscript of 1. If you are familiar with latex, I need : $\hat{\xi}_1$

I know this can be done easily in other programs, I hate Excel too, but I need it in Excel. Is there a way to actually do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Unicode on fonts that support it. You want 'GREEK SMALL LETTER XI' (U+03BE) + 'COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT' (U+0302) to form ξ̂.

To enter these codes on various platforms, consult [this entry in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Hexadecimal_code_input). In Office, you should be able to enter "3BE" then press Alt-x, then enter "302" and press Alt-x again to get the combined character.

Comment: What's the method for getting those to show up using the code?  I.e., I know certain ASCII character codes can be entered in Windows by holding down Alt and pressing the correct digits on the numeric keypad, but I don't know how to do that for unicode characters.

Comment: @Marc I've added some info on entry - the method varies by OS.

Comment: @chthoicdaemon, that's really helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Btw, I could not insert them using alt-x (that selects the add-ins tab in the ribbon). I had to do it in MS word and then copy and paste to the label. It works, but looks wierd (the hat overlaps with the xi letter).

Answer (score -1):

On the `Insert` menu on the ribbon, choose `Symbol` (far right on my ribbon).

On the symbol dialog, choose Font: "Normal Text" and Subset: "Greek and Coptic".  Unicode 039E appears to be what you want.

If you can't get to the Symbol dialog while simultaneously in your Y-Axis chart dialog, just copy the symbol onto the clipboard and paste it in where you need it.